# Minify and join CSS & JS files on linux, server side

Tags: javascript, css, linux, command-line, minify

In my project, for example, I have this structure:

```
/public/js/src/ /* many jquery plugins there */
/public/css/src/ /* many css files there, that describe different things */
```

After changes have been made, I would like to type in command line something like:

```
root@hostname:/var/www/test/public# ./build
```

which would generate two files:

```
/public/css/build.css - all files from /public/css/src/ folder with minified source
/public/js/build.js - all files from /public/js/src folder with minified source
```

---

For the moment I am using less css, which is working on node. I would like to have one script that will do everything, for css as for javascript. Could you please advise the best way to "build" dev-source javascript & css files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [YUI Compressor](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/). I'm sure it's also available for Linux. 
It works from the command line. [Read here](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/README.md) how it works.

Example:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar myfile.js -o myfile-min.js --charset utf-8
```

I'm sure you can setup a simple Bash script that executes two commands, one for CSS and one for JS by using parameters as input.

Comment: Yep, YUI Compressor works great all over the place (Linux, Mac..)

Answer (score 4):

YUI-Compressor is available as a package in any Ubuntu version.

```
apt-get install yui-compressor
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache ANT and YUI Compressor to set up your own build process. You can minify all your JS and CSS files with a single command.

EDIT: if you want a sample project try H5bp's ant build scripts http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for those getting here through Google. You can easily use Compass for this.

```
compass compile --output-style compressed --force
```

More info: http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/production-css/

Answer (score 1):

Use ACCSS for css compression, its compression rate is better than YUI-Compressors and its written in c with automake installation, so it is portable to almost every system.

Like above, you can use a shell script to combine less and accss. accss support reading from stdin, so you can combine them with

`lessc styles.less | accss > out.css`

It also has severeal compatibility options, especially for Internet Explorer.

https://github.com/acwtools/accss